# $Y= -3\sin2x + 3\cos2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sum of $\sin$ and $\cos$ 
My question is what is the phase shif ? 
When i tried it by the reduction identity i get the phase shift is $3\pi/8$ to the left but my teacher says it is $3\pi/4$
So what is the correct answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$Y= -3\sin2x + 3\cos2x=3(\cos 2x-\sin2x)=3[\cos2x-\cos(\pi/2-2x)] $$

Now use:

$$\cos A-\cos B=-2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Y=3\cos(2x+\pi/4)=3\cos2(x+\pi/8)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Y= -3\sin2x + 3\cos2x=3\sqrt 2 (\cos 2x \cos \pi /4 -\sin 2x \sin \pi /4) =$$

$$ 3\sqrt 2 \cos (2x+\pi /4)=$$

$$ 3\sqrt 2 \cos (2x- 7\pi /4)= 3\sqrt 2 \cos 2 (x- 7\pi /8) $$